# Open offline Clickhouse database using clickhouse-local

Tags: clickhouse

I wonder whether it is possible to open an offline clickhouse database (i.e. clickhouse-server not running) using the [`clickhouse-local` tool](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/utilities/clickhouse-local/)

This might be possible since the `Native` input-format should actually be the same as the on-disk format in `/var/lib/clickhouse/data/...`

The problem I am facing still is how to read multiple of the column-files within one invocation of `clickhouse-local`

It would be very cool to be able to do that since it gives a good feeling to be able to rescue data from a database that doesn't launch anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has no sense.
CH does not have a system catalog. You can manually fix metadata .sql or parts.

clickhouse-local is the same binary as server. It's the same tool.

clickhouse-local is just a synonym (symbolic link)

```
ls  -l /usr/bin/clickhouse-local
   /usr/bin/clickhouse-local -> clickhouse

ls -l /usr/bin/clickhouse-server
   /usr/bin/clickhouse-server -> clickhouse
```

> It would be very cool to be able to do that since it gives
> a good feeling to be able to rescue data from a database that
> doesn't launch anymore.

No difference, you can use even clickhouse-client.